# Drumkit maintenance

Tags: maintenance, drums

I was reading questions randomly and this one grabbed my attention:

[Piano Maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10600/piano-maintenance)

Accordingly, you put glasses of water in the piano to help keep the humidity steady, so that its wood lasts longer. Especially in the summer, because wood does not do well in hot places.  Is this also applicable to a drumkit, since both instruments include wood?

My assumption is that the wood from which a piano is made is stronger. So if a piano needs this maintenance, should a drumkit, which has weaker wood, also need that maintenance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should help, although the main reason for keeping the humidity and temperature the same for a piano is to help keep it in tune.

Nonetheless, keeping drum sets in a stable environment is helpful in other ways.

This article [here](http://www.shinemusic.com.au/musicresources/How-to-maintain-Drum-kit.aspx) addresses this, and some other things you can do to maintain a drum set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will help.  Wood of the drum kit may weaken when exposed to heat.  It would be helpful if you keep that maintenance.